# Should a URL match the page's title?

Tags: seo, url, title

Should the URL of a page match its title? For example:

```
Http://example.com/about-cats.html

<title>About Cats</title>
```

Furthermore, if that title were to be changed by the page's author, should the URL change to match and the old URL be redirected (301) to the new URL?

**Edit**

Also, if the pages author were to decide to revert his changes after several days, would it be right to remove the redirect and set up an new redirect from the amended URL back to the old URL?

Comment: Presumably you are asking this from an SEO perspective? (I've added the SEO tag.)

Comment: Whenever you change the URL (for whatever reason) you will need to setup a 301 redirect and these redirects will probably need to be left in indefinitely. eg. 5 URL changes; 5 redirects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the content of the `title` element and the path of the URL don't have to match.

Think of all the sites that use only IDs in the URL path, e.g. YouTube:

- URL: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP4NMoJcFd4`
- Title: `Songify This - CAN&#39;T HUG EVERY CAT (now on iTunes) -- a song about loving cats - YouTube`

Also, most of the times the `title` content will be rather long, while it's often advisable for URLs to be short:

- URL: `http://example.com/shop/cant-hug-every-cat`
- Title: `Music video (DVD): "Can't hug every cat" (2011) by "The Gregory Brothers" and "Cara Hartmann" – example.com`

Comment: Two things to back that up: Here are Google's [recommendations for titles](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35624), and here is our recommendation with regards to [dynamic vs rewritten URLs](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html). Make the title relevant to the page, and don't worry about having to create a fake, static-looking URL.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Very Much. If you are talking in the Point of SERP AND SEO. It does require matching Title with URL. and it should have 75 Characters in Title and URL.

Comment: Pointing to a specific article on your site that answers the question is OK. Pointing to a category URL doesn't answer the question.